# Como usar a ABS do firebird 2.1 > no firebird 2.0?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, firebird, firebase-database

Tenho um cliente que já tem um sistema que roda no firebird 2.0 e o meu sistema roda na versão mais nova do firebird, com isso tive que regredir a database e tem algumas funções que o 2.0 não tem ainda... Como eu poderia fazer o ABS(pegar numero absoluto) no firebird 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar as `DLL's` da pasta de instalação padrão do `Firebird`:

```
DECLARE EXTERNAL FUNCTION abs 
DOUBLE PRECISION
RETURNS DOUBLE PRECISION BY VALUE
ENTRY_POINT 'IB_UDF_abs' MODULE_NAME 'ib_udf';
```